# get dynamic data from the slot ? not added resolutionsPerAuthority's dynamic element in the list

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to get dynamic data from the slot
As per documentation and my basic test  I am sending directive from launch request as like :

```
{'version': '1.0', 'response': {'outputSpeech': {'type': 'SSML', 'ssml': '<speak> Hi, welcome to developement dynamic slot. <break time="800ms"/>Please tell me the product name you would be interested in</speak>'}, 'card': {'type': 'Simple', 'title': 'Choose a Medicine.', 'content': 'Pick a Medicine.'}, 'reprompt': {'outputSpeech': {'type': 'SSML', 'ssml': '<speak><break time="5s"/>I am HERE to help You, Please tell me the product and country names you would be interested in.</speak>'}}, 'shouldEndSession': False}, 'directives': [{'type': 'Dialog.UpdateDynamicEntities', 'updateBehavior': 'REPLACE', 'types': [{'name': 'products', 'values': [{'id': 'grnTea', 'name': {'value': 'green tea', 'synonyms': ['matcha']}}, {'id': 'oolTea', 'name': {'value': 'oolong', 'synonyms': ['chinese tea', 'black dragon tea']}}]}]}]}
```

and when I'm trying to get data which is **not statically store in a slot** but added in directive slot value.
returns following output :

```
{ "version": "1.0", "session": { "new": false, "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.671181ed-1e50-4e4c-b70e-4d854fe7cb78", "application": { "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.c35cd12c-6845-473e-be58-9b1139ee0adb" }, "user": { "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.sadasdsa", "permissions": { "consentToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ..XyWgyUIjDzzlZ12CR0lbZid6GxwZZYBgarlV-9difbkFjOTxrcvS9lJYWo-Db3wo-fIdXb_jZkCAJBtYPggqnJhLyyC-EDa0_u9aARKthF1_nkbLh5zDOHDb8MyyOYro4BJlqm4XBNd1qyeQUV2M4fdca1YSEnbEun_6kWOKeFRS-14zcwMj5E-MHcBbeDX799A_kay82kS8VGeMhSUsXPTZFrwOKHcFweJTqXFNOkBxME8kAFfS1JB5MNbA3TujVIsIgTBSNQaJeHRksConKt0u06ATrjffzFkcmbxDT5HoJH4NqDgS0y_GdtaeXQM3LJ-MN0-_DMX2QVEaL6kUUw" } } }, "context": { "System": { "application": { "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.c35cd12c-6845-473e-be58-9b1139ee0adb" }, "user": { "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.aasdasdasdasdas", "permissions": { "consentToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.asdjaskdhas.XyWgyUIjDzzlZ12CR0lbZid6GxwZZYBgarlV-9difbkFjOTxrcvS9lJYWo-Db3wo-fIdXb_jZkCAJBtYPggqnJhLyyC-EDa0_u9aARKthF1_nkbLh5zDOHDb8MyyOYro4BJlqm4XBNd1qyeQUV2M4fdca1YSEnbEun_6kWOKeFRS-14zcwMj5E-MHcBbeDX799A_kay82kS8VGeMhSUsXPTZFrwOKHcFweJTqXFNOkBxME8kAFfS1JB5MNbA3TujVIsIgTBSNQaJeHRksConKt0u06ATrjffzFkcmbxDT5HoJH4NqDgS0y_GdtaeXQM3LJ-MN0-_DMX2QVEaL6kUUw" } }, "device": { "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.ajshdjkhasjkhdkjsahkasdhjasd", "supportedInterfaces": {} }, "apiEndpoint": "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com", "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.asdhjashjdhajsd.RQhzWmnhN9K_dCbsFXBPPoLVzuwe5BWjAruwJNF1pVr11PiygVgQ64W3CNng2sK1thT2tl6r3GuRtG-1133Aw1KPWtMuHElu7CTrFfgAqW8blpK37PJIvPMOUGBw1rbrgCTMdy8Ua7qSFV_Y_wlOJaV3-apDGBqhQKE_-dE-ntWYZuIySlY3l8hBs_66eELS-LiL5DEDJk1hfvC2C6ZFB7A7P8mx4Hb71km-lYaElJS0-FDP0C-LdSp6dCbzV23W4JehtTGL4kJ1JEQgWyuNAAkt_HmPcEYlPp8T5RFceDuVuz-ZZBFyiVKuAN8VmxyFsmnC3SXi4yb3RKm1SCcorg" }, "Viewport": { "experiences": [ { "arcMinuteWidth": 246, "arcMinuteHeight": 144, "canRotate": false, "canResize": false } ], "shape": "RECTANGLE", "pixelWidth": 1024, "pixelHeight": 600, "dpi": 160, "currentPixelWidth": 1024, "currentPixelHeight": 600, "touch": [ "SINGLE" ], "video": { "codecs": [ "H_264_42", "H_264_41" ] } }, "Viewports": [ { "type": "APL", "id": "main", "shape": "RECTANGLE", "dpi": 160, "presentationType": "STANDARD", "canRotate": false, "configuration": { "current": { "video": { "codecs": [ "H_264_42", "H_264_41" ] }, "size": { "type": "DISCRETE", "pixelWidth": 1024, "pixelHeight": 600 } } } } ] }, "request": { "type": "IntentRequest", "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.0f3b51f1-880b-483f-8410-3210e81e5b59", "timestamp": "2020-01-01T11:48:09Z", "locale": "en-IN", "intent": { "name": "productcheck", "confirmationStatus": "NONE", "slots": { "products": { "name": "products", "value": "green tea", "resolutions": { "resolutionsPerAuthority": [ { "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.c35cd12c-6845-473e-be58-9b1139ee0adb.products", "status": { "code": "ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH" } } ] }, "confirmationStatus": "NONE", "source": "USER" } } } } }
```

It's not added resolutions resolutionsPerAuthority's second(dynamic) element in the list.
anybody can help me out from this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your added directive exactly as pasted and the dynamic entity resolved as expected:

```
"slots": {
    "products": {
      "name": "products",
      "value": "matcha",
      "resolutions": {
        "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
          {
            "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.****.products",
            "status": {
              "code": "ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH"
            }
          },
          {
            "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.dynamic.amzn1.ask.skill.****.products",
            "status": {
              "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
            },
            "values": [
              {
                "value": {
                  "name": "green tea",
                  "id": "grnTea"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
      "source": "USER"
    }
  }
```

Could you share your skill's interaction model to investigate further?